# exim paniclog mainlog 10gb+ > remote_smtp transport called with no hosts set

Tags: logging, centos, exim

I am encoutering the following

exim mainlog and paniclog all exceed 10GB of data (and this is clogging my server: CentOS release 6.4 (Final))

The repeating message that I could tail from mainlog is

> remote_smtp transport called with no hosts set 2013-12-24 07:42:12
>   1VmDSU-0002bQ-T6 == root@myserver.com R=local

I thought I'd solved this before - but apparently not.

Any idea how I can debug this? Or find yout what is creating this repetitive message?

I didn't find any articles on this topic

thx - Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a router named **local** that designates an smtp transport but without giving it any kind of host where you want the smtp message transported.

Can you provide the output to the following command?

```
exim -bv -v root@myserver.com
```

That should at least give us some more insight into what your configuration is trying to do.

Can you also tell us what your **local** router configuration looks like in exim.conf?

Comment: I could .. but in the meantime reinstalled exim ... and now it is working. I think we manually changed something before ...